# How can I send augur token from one account to another one using JSON-RPC api?

Tags: erc-20

I looked for if eth_sendTransaction method enables me to realize what I'm asking, but I couldn't find sure information, so I want to make sure.

params: [{
  "from": "One account ",
  "to":"another one ",
  "gas": "0x76c0", // 30400
  "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000", // 10000000000000
  "data":"augur's abi"
  "value":"whatever "
}]

So will the call work as I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not particularly close. :-)

- `to` should be the address of the token contract, since that's the recipient of the function invocation.
- `value` should be 0. (It's the amount of ether sent.)
- `data` should be the hexadecimal representation of the first four bytes of the keccak256 hash of the function signature (`transfer(address,uint256)`) followed by the address of the recipient, left-padded to be 32 bytes long, followed by the amount to be transferred, again encoded as a 32-byte integer.

Of course, there are libraries (including `web3.js`) that will compute the `data` for you given the ABI and parameters.

Comment: So how can I send augur from one account to the other via JSON-RPC Api?

Comment: I already told you in great detail in my answer.

Comment: Sorry I kinda misread.in brief, I can send token using the transfer method in the eth_sendTransaction method,right? my English ability is not perfect that's why I'm making it sure.Sorry

Comment: Yes, that's right.